# How to sum a column of a pandas dataframe and keep only the result of the sum as the value of the column

Tags: python, pandas

There is a dataframe :

[image]

The final result I would like to get is:

[image]

I use the method :

```
df_one['Number'] = df_one['Number'].sum()

df_one['Amount'] = df_one['Amount'].sum()
```

It doesn't achieve the results I want, what method should I use to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) for `Series` and then convert it to one row `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) with transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df1 = df.sum().to_frame().T
```

Comment: Hi Jez. Why would you use ```.agg``` here? How come not just ```df.sum().to_frame().T``` ?

Comment: @sophocles - oops, you are right. `agg` is for possible defined multiple different functions per columns